# Display math equations in web view

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

In my project i am using `WebView`and `jqMath` to display mathematical equations and it is working for single line equations but for equations with numerator and denominator it is not working properly, it is not showing the separator line between numerator and denominator. I've copied the html file and javascript libraries and in `assets` folder and loading it from there. I've attached the screenshots [image: This one is from the jqMath website]
This one is from the jqMath site and is displaying properly in Chrome

and this one is from my genymotion emulator.i was trying to display the above equation in `webview` and the result is like this  [image]
Can anyone suggest a way to fix this.

Comment: Sony> Do you know the answer to this jqmath question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36526435/jqmath-not-loading-correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the css file and copied it to the assets folder and everything works as expected